# How do I get the p-value when using Java's OLSMultipleLinearRegression?

Tags: regression, java

I'm doing my regression using Apache's [OLSMultipleLinearRegression class](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/regression/OLSMultipleLinearRegression.html).

How do I get the p-value?  Is there another name for p-value that I should be looking for in the docs?

EDIT: I have the regression params and the standard error for each param.  Is it reasonable to calculate my own p-values?  Any reason this wouldn't be in the Apache library?

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer in a different SE--we deal more with concepts than software here...

Comment: Cross-posted to StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768019/how-do-i-get-the-p-value-when-using-javas-olsmultiplelinearregression

Comment: I also have this question, do you find the answer?